# Bootstrap list with close button on right

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to draw some elements with bootstrap but I'm stuck and I need a little bit of help to see how can I fix that.
My problem is close related to html scheme and looks like :

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item items-orange">This is option one from pair one</li>
            <li class="list-group-item items-blue">This is option two from pair one</li>
        </ul>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="button">Close Button</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

so how can I put that button from bottom to right in continuation of li elements like in picture below:
[image]

**[fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/ZurAk/226/)**

Comment: i cant see that image can you please draw structure??

Comment: @SwapnilMotewar I can see the image just fine.

Comment: You mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ZurAk/228/

Comment: @DavidG He wants it so that they are like the picture shown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add a few classes to your markup. Notice how it scales properly with different browser widths.

http://jsfiddle.net/NateW/ZurAk/233/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="container">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item custom">
        <ul class="list-group options">
            <li class="list-group-item items-orange">This is option one from pair one</li>
            <li class="list-group-item items-blue">This is option two from pair one</li>
        </ul>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger side-btn" type="button">Close Button</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{padding:40px;}
li.list-group-item {
    overflow:auto;
}
.side-btn{
    float:left;
    width:15%;
    white-space: normal;
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    bottom: 30px;
}
li.custom {
    padding:0;
}
ul.options {
    width: 85%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-button-right">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item items-orange">This is option one from pair one</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item items-blue">This is option two from pair one</li>
                </ul>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="button">Close Button</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding:40px;
}
.list-group-button-right {
    position: relative;
}
.list-group-button-right button {

    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 15px;
    height: 82px;
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/ZurAk/229/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

I know is not perfect or the best way to do it, but this could help you a bit http://jsfiddle.net/ZurAk/232/

```
<div class="container">

     <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="search" class="form-control" name="searchBy" id="searchBy"/>
        <input type="search"  class="form-control" name="searchBy" id="searchBy"/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button id="filter" class="btn btn-primary" style="height:4.85em;">Close Button</button>
        </span>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is half custom build, half bootstrap,
see: http://jsfiddle.net/bb7pbuqx/2/

html:

```
<div id="outer_container"  class="container">
    <div id="inner_container" class="container">
        <div id="list_container" class="container">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item items-orange">This is option one from pair one</li>
                <li class="list-group-item items-blue">This is option two from pair one</li>
                <li class="list-group-item items-blue">This is option two from pair one</li>
                <li class="list-group-item items-blue">This is option two from pair one</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="button_container" class="container">            
            <button id="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="button">Close Button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
body{padding:40px;}

#outer_container
{
    position:relative;
}

#list_container
{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

}
    #list_container ul
    {
        margin:0 ;
        padding:0 ;

    }
    #list_container li
    {
        border-top-right-radius:0px;    
        border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    }


#button_container
{
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
}
    #button_container button
    {
        position:absolute;
        height:100%;
        left:0;

        border-top-left-radius:0px;   
        border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    }
```